# Modules in Python on Windows

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, cairo

I have a simple sode snippet that uses `cairo`module. I would like to launch the scipt but it somehow cannot run giving this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named cairo
```

how should I "install" a module in Python on Windows ? I have tried installing http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/ as stated on [cairo page](http://cairographics.org/download/)  that I can get cairo as a "side effect" of intalling GTK+ but somehow this didn't work.

If I should add some paths to `PATH` please indicate which one as I am raelly confused about this.

Now I realise how simpler that would be on linux with powerful terminal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing PyGtk from here: http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html. The [all-in-one-installer](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/) worked for me. Just choose the packages you want installed.

Comment: That helped, thanks. But I would like to get minimal possible install. I know I can install [PyCairo](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pycairo/1.8/pycairo-1.8.10.win32-py2.7.msi) but I do not know where to put this [cairo package](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/cairo_1.10.2-2_win32.zip)

Comment: It should place it where your python environment tells it to.